# how to localize text in unity into a separate file

Tags: unity-game-engine, localization

I'm looking for localization in unity where I can organize all of our text into a file like this:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml

by keeping all of our text in a file like that, I could upload it to a localization service where it could be translated into a Spanish language file like this:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml

I saw this video about localization in unity, but it keeps all the text inside of unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lku7f4KNFEo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Unity's Localization system, You can export your `String Table` into different formats to know how to look into the `Extensions` part of Unity's Localization documentation.

[Localization Documentation Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.4/manual/CSV.html)